# Python ModuleNotFoundError while importing from another directory

Tags: python, import

I have a directory structure like this

```
-project
    --folder1
        ---file1.py
    --folder2
        ---file2.py
```

How can I import a function from *file2* and use it in *file1*?
I tried to

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../folder2/')
from file2 import foo
foo()
```

and this doesn't work.
I tried to include `__init__.py` in each folder at it didn't work either.
Do I have an error with the relative path, or what should I do?

Comment: `this doesn't work` is not an error message. Please include the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple solution you can add the "absolute" path to the **project** directory and then put `from folder2.file2 import foo` in *file1.py* like :

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, <absolute path to "project" direcotry>)

from folder2.file2 import foo

foo()
```

now you can run your `file1.py` directly, python will find `folder2` and therefore `file2`.

---

Alternatively you can add the "absolute" path to the **folder2** directory and then put `from file2 import foo` in *file1.py* like:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, <absolute path to "project" folder2>)

from file2 import foo

foo()
```

now you can run your `file1.py` directly, python will find `file2`.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now, but why I can't do it with a relative path?

Comment: @AhmedMoataz This is from doc : *Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always `"__main__"`, modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports.*. Of course this is python and you can manipulate `__package__` to do that but I don't recommend. either use absolute import or use relative import but do not call your main file (here file1.py) directly. If file1 gets imported into another let's say main.py , the relative imports inside it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

use `import folder2.file2` or `from folder2.file2 import function_name`

PS: Your project directory should be in python path

Comment: `from folder2.file2 import <function_name>`